# I need preg_match_all() pattern in getting string inside square bracket tags PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to parse a string to get the value inside a square bracket tag:

`[vc_column_text][/vc_column_text]`

I am using `preg_match_all()` in PHP

```
$string = '[vc_row][vc_column][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="1/2"][vc_column_text css=".vc_custom_1576642149231{margin-bottom: 0px !important;}"]This is the string I want to fetch[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row]`;
```

I tried this:

```
preg_match_all("'[vc_column_text(.*?)](.*?)[/vc_column_text]'", $string, $matches);
```

But this only returns an array of 2-3 characters:

[image]

A help will be very much appreciated :)

Comment: do you mean like this? `\[vc_column_text([^][]*)\](.*?)\[/vc_column_text]`  https://regex101.com/r/IMw4br/1 Or like this matching only the sentence `\[vc_column_text[^][]*\]\s*(.*?)\[/vc_column_text]` https://regex101.com/r/Awd3gr/1

Comment: @Jeram In your own expression, you forgot to escape the opening square brackets, which leads the regex engine to treat `[vc_column_text(.*?)]` as a character class over the set of contained characters. So, change both `[...` to `\[...` in your regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match only the sentence, you could use first match `[vc_column_text` followed by any char except `[` or `]` and then match the closing `]`

Then match 0+ occurrences of a whitespace char and capture 1 or more occurrences of any char except a whitespace in group 1.

```
\[vc_column_text[^][]*\]\s*(.+?)\[/vc_column_text]
```

**Explanation**

- `\[vc_column_text` Match `[vc_column_text`
- `[^][]*\]` Match `[`, then 0+ occurrences of any char except `[` or `]` and match `]`
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `(.+?)` Capture group 1, match any char 1+ times non greedy
- `\[/vc_column_text]` Match `[/vc_column_text]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f9SGor/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/irhtr)

Example code

```
$string = '[vc_row][vc_column][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="1/2"][vc_column_text css=".vc_custom_1576642149231{margin-bottom: 0px !important;}"]This is the string I want to fetch[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row]';
preg_match_all("~\[vc_column_text[^][]*\]\s*(.+?)\[/vc_column_text]~", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is the string I want to fetch
)
```

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird. here's my final code based on thw pattern you gave:

`preg_match_all("~\[vc_column_text[^][]*\]\s*(.+?)\[/vc_column_text]~ms", $string, $matches);`